# ERC20 token vs CW20 token

Tags: tokens, erc-20

What I found about [CW20 token](https://github.com/CosmWasm/cosmwasm-plus/blob/main/packages/cw20/README.md) is loosely based on ERC20 token.
What methods are different in CW20 token comparing to ERC20 token and what method might additionally exist in CW20 token?

Comment: You should edit your question to post a link to a description of what CW20 is. I never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link you shared: https://github.com/CosmWasm/cosmwasm-plus/blob/main/packages/cw20/README.md

Answer (score 1):

It's the same if both blockchain  base on EVM Blockchain.